# RestTemplate modifying URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, url, resttemplate

Today i have encountered a strange situation: url ending in `&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin` is modified by Rest template to `&timezone=Europe%252FBerlin`
Somehow there is 52 added between 2 and %

Here is a brakepoint in debug:

```
@Nullable
public <T> T execute(String uriTemplate, HttpMethod method, @Nullable RequestCallback requestCallback, @Nullable ResponseExtractor<T> responseExtractor, Object... uriVariables) throws RestClientException {
    URI url = this.getUriTemplateHandler().expand(uriTemplate, uriVariables); // https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&current_weather=true&hourly=temperature_2m,rain,snowfall,weathercode,surface_pressure,visibility,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m&daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,sunrise,sunset&start_date=2023-04-01&end_date=2023-04-03&timezone=Europe%252FBerlin
    return this.doExecute(url, uriTemplate, method, requestCallback, responseExtractor);
}
```

Also screen:
[image]

Below is the rest of the code:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class OpenMeteoService {

    final String baseUrl = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?";

    String setLocalization(Double lat, Double lon) {
        String latValue = lat.toString().replace(",", ".");
        String lonValue = lon.toString().replace(",", ".");
        return String.format("latitude=%s&longitude=%s&current_weather=true", latValue, lonValue);
    }

    String getHourlyForecast(boolean temperature, boolean rain, boolean snowfall, boolean weathercode, boolean pressure, boolean visibility, boolean windSpeed, boolean windDirection) {
        String base = "&hourly=";
        if (temperature) base += "temperature_2m,";
        if (rain) base += "rain,";
        if (snowfall) base += "snowfall,";
        if (weathercode) base += "weathercode,";
        if (pressure) base += "surface_pressure,";
        if (visibility) base += "visibility,";
        if (windSpeed) base += "windspeed_10m,";
        if (windDirection) base += "winddirection_10m,";

        return base.substring(0, base.length() - 1);
    }

    String getDailyWeather(boolean temperatureMax, boolean temperatureMin, boolean sunrise, boolean sunset) {
        ;
        String base = "&daily=";
        if (temperatureMax) base += "temperature_2m_max,";
        if (temperatureMin) base += "temperature_2m_min,";
        if (sunrise) base += "sunrise,";
        if (sunset) base += "sunset,";

        return base.substring(0, base.length() - 1);
    }

    String getDates(String start, String end) {
        return String.format("&start_date=%s&end_date=%s", start, end) + "&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin";
    }

    String getFullUrl(Double lat, Double lon, String start, String end) {
        return baseUrl +
                setLocalization(lat, lon) +
                getHourlyForecast(true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true) +
                getDailyWeather(true, true, true, true) +
                getDates(start, end);
    }

}
```

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class OpenMeteoServiceTest {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class OpenMeteoServiceTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        OpenMeteoService openMeteoService() {
            return new OpenMeteoService();
        }

        ;
    }

    @Autowired
    OpenMeteoService openMeteoService;


    @Test
    void get_dates_should_return_valid_url_for_entered_dates() {
        //given
        String start = "2023-04-01";
        String end = "2023-04-30";

        //when
        String result = openMeteoService.getDates(start, end);

        //then
        assertEquals("&start_date=2023-04-01&end_date=2023-04-30&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin", result);
    }

    @Test
    void get_full_url_should_return_valid_url_for_entered_values() {
        //given
        double lat = 52.52;
        double lon = 13.41;
        String start = "2023-04-01";
        String end = "2023-04-03";

        //when
        String result = openMeteoService.getFullUrl(lat, lon, start, end);

        //then
        assertEquals("https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&current_weather=true&hourly=temperature_2m,rain,snowfall,weathercode,surface_pressure,visibility,windspeed_10m,winddirection_10m&daily=temperature_2m_max,temperature_2m_min,sunrise,sunset&start_date=2023-04-01&end_date=2023-04-03&timezone=Europe%2FBerlin",
                result);
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        //given
        double lat = 52.52;
        double lon = 13.41;
        String start = "2023-04-01";
        String end = "2023-04-03";
        String url = openMeteoService.getFullUrl(lat, lon, start, end);
        System.out.println(url);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        OpenMeteoEntity forObject = restTemplate.getForObject(url, OpenMeteoEntity.class);
        System.out.println(forObject);
    }
}
```

What is the reason this is happening and how to fix this? As you can imagine, API refuses it

Comment: That’s the automatic urlencoder converting % into %25 because % is a special character. Change Europe%2FBerlin in your code to Europe/Berlin and the same encoder will sort it out for you.

Comment: Thank you, this works, you should post this as an answer so I would accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the automatic urlencoder converting `%` into `%25` because % is a special character. Change `Europe%2FBerlin` in your code to `Europe/Berlin` and the same encoder will sort it out for you.